# How do I get rid of human readable format for ls?

Tags: osx, ls

My ls -l command automatically prints file sizes as human readable. I have tried exporting BLOCKSIZE in my bash profile in various formats to change this but literally everything I have tried on the ls man page or online is not working.
When I use `stat -f "%z bytes"` myfile.tar.gz it prints as 877702 bytes, but my ls -l command prints it as 857K.

I just want to see the full file size printed with at least 6 digits as I see some people's terminals can do. Mine cannot. I even checked my bashrc file which does not have any exports of ls to change this.

I am using MacOSX Mojave.

Comment: What does `type ls` show you?

Comment: You appear to have created two accounts. Please go to [the Contact page](/contact) and select “I need to merge user profiles”.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it - Even though my bashrc file did not have any ls alias to change the output, once I commented out my bash_profile from sourcing bashrc and exporting BLOCKSIZE to 1024K I can see the full size in bytes now.

Comment: If your `.bash_profile` was sourcing your `.bashrc`, then commenting out the `source` command is probably overkill and may break something.  You should probably just comment out the line in `.bashrc` that sets (and exports) BLOCKSIZE.

Comment: You appear to have created two accounts. Please go to [the Contact page](/contact) and select “I need to merge user profiles”.